# Cannot access GridGain 6.0 Maven repository

Tags: gridgain

This question is mainly for the GridGain support team.

We are trying to access the GridGain 6.0 repository but our corporate firewall is blocking it because it is using a non-standard port number:

```
<repository>
  <id>GridGain External Repository</id>
  <url>http://www.gridgainsystems.com:8085/nexus/content/repositories/external</url>
</repository>
```

Is there a reason why port 8085 is used instead of port 80?  Is there another URL we can use which has the standard port number?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

GridGain has been moved to Maven Central. You don't need to specify repository anymore.